# how to manage Image caches in ios when using 2 caching libraries

Tags: uiimage, xcode6, sdwebimage, qlpreviewcontroller, image-caching

I am using SDWebImage image loaded as the default image loader, I also use AZAPreviewController to display images in the Fullscreen view.

AZAPreviewController using its own cache folder to maintain caches for the same images but images are not display in iOS-8 when trying to fetch for AZAPreviewItem.

Can anyone please help me for that or can anyone suggest any better preview controller (full screen image viewer) with iOS8 support.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**AZAPreview controller** and **SDWebImage** both have different working mechanism.

**AZAPreviewController** uses QLPreviewcontroller of ios as super class which save images as file with extension in document directory. If it exists, directly fetch image from directory, Other wise download from url and save into document directory.

While **SDWebImage** store images as NSDATA and store data into the directory folder. When loading any image fetch data and convert it intto the UIImage.

So in general, if we use both the library single image will be stored twice which consumes memory and not efficient way.

I have found one preview controller **[MWPhotos][1] which** uses SDWebImage as its sub library to load images which do NOT create any conflict in storing data and better to keep less caching memory.

So, conclude to use to use MWPhotoBrowser when we required Preview controller with SDWebImage as caching library.

MWPhotoBrower Reference Project :   [1]: https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWPhotoBrowser

Thanks.